# Replacing kitchen wall tiles

Tags: kitchens, ceramic-tile

If my kitchen wall tiles start some centimeters below the countertop and the base cabinets, can I replace the tiles without moving the cabinets? For example by cutting the tiles at the countertop line and replacing only from this line and up?
I know it's not the cleanest way but, given that I will never see what's behind the cabinets, does it matter?

Thank you.

Comment: It's unlikely to look good where you CAN see it if you are doing that, IMHO.

Comment: I agree with Jack, I would probably score and snap them then push the pieces down, trying to do in place without messing up the counter top may be a tall order. A photo may give us other ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it. You'd need a small portable tile saw and would have to very carefully cut the tiles exactly flush with the countertop. This would be very hard to do because you'd have to reach to the back of the countertop to do the cutting and would need perfect control of the saw to avoid scratching the countertop. If you were that skilled, because of past experience, with the saw, you'd probably realize it's not a good idea to do this and you'd unscrew the base cabinets and move them out a bit and do the job right.